# hitting enter in a textbox on IE (9), goes to next input

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

**when I hit enter in a textbox on IE 9 on some pages the cursor goes to next input/button, which is not what I need.**

**anybody knows why is this happening and how to stop this ?**

I tried creating jsbin or jsfiddle for this, but they dont really work on IE, in jsbin you can't type in the textbox, and in jsfiddle hitting enter in the textbox redirects you to a website

http://jsfiddle.net/tG9An/

```
  <input type='text' name='search' />
  <input type='text' name='search2' />
```

http://jsbin.com/itelub/2/edit

Comment: jsFiddle works just fine in IE 9. Older than that, no. In the fiddle you provided, pressing enter does nothing special. It might, if it were in a form.

Comment: @Ian for me using IE9 on http://jsfiddle.net/tG9An/ hitting enter in the first textbox will redirect to https://www.gittip.com/JSFiddle/

Comment: You might try placing a <form> element around the fields. In general, fields aren’t allowed outside of a form element, and the browser may not behave as expected.

Comment: @Omu Hmm weird. It must be because I'm using IE10 and emulating IE9. I still wouldn't expect anything to happen, without a form

Comment: This isn't a default browser behavior. Either you've got script that's doing this, or you have a browser plugin that's doing it.

Comment: @EricLaw I actually found the problem already, it's when there is a button tag without type="button" and you hit enter in a textbox, the cursor will focus that button and click it